# How can I grab all possible results based on values in an SQL table when dealing with user permissions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli

I have 5 tables, and only 4 of which are needed to grab the results I want. These tables are:

```
--------------
| Roles      |
--------------
| ID | NAME  |
--------------
| 1  | Admin |
--------------
| 2  | User  |
--------------

-------------
| USERS     |
-------------
| ID | NAME |
-------------
| 1  | Dan |
-------------
| 2  | Dave  |
-------------
| 3  | Mike |
-------------

--------------------------------
|         navigation           |
--------------------------------
| ID         | navlinks        |
--------------------------------
| 1          | Home            |
--------------------------------
| 2          | Admin Page      |
--------------------------------
```

Table used for assigning a users role

```
--------------------------
| user_roles             |
--------------------------
| ID | user_id | role_id |
--------------------------
| 1  | 1       | 1       |
--------------------------
| 2  | 2       | 2       |
--------------------------
| 3  | 3       | 1       |
--------------------------
```

Table used for assigning allowed user_roles to each navigation navlink

```
----------------------------------
| navigation_roles               |
----------------------------------
| ID | navigation_id | user_role |
----------------------------------
| 1  | 1             | 1         |
----------------------------------
| 2  | 1             | 2         |
----------------------------------
| 3  | 2             | 1         |
----------------------------------
```

I want to be able to grab the `user.name` column and the `navigation.navigation_name` column that each user is allowed access to.

Dan and Dave should be shown the Admin and Home link, while Mike should only see Home. But my solution only shows both the Admin and Home for Dave only and Dan only has the Home link when he should also be shown the Admin link.

```
select users.name, navigation.navlinks FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_roles on users.id = user_roles.user_id
LEFT JOIN navigation_roles ON navigation_roles.role_id = user_roles.role_id
RIGHT JOIN navigation on navigation.id = navigation_roles.navigation_id;
```

So the above shows me:

```
----------------
| Dan  | Home  |
----------------
| Dave | Home  |
----------------
| Mike | Home  |
----------------
| Dave | Admin |
----------------
```

When it should be showing me:

```
----------------
| Dan  | Home  |
----------------
| Dave | Home  |
----------------
| Mike | Home  |
----------------
| Dave | Admin |
----------------
| Dan  | Admin |
----------------
```

Comment: Only the `role_id` of 2 have access to `Admin` and `Home` and `Mike` is the only one with `role_id` of 2. Your initial result is correct.

Comment: You helped me realize my error Felix, and thanks for the edit. I need to figure out how to post on here haha

Comment: No problem, you did a better job than most new users. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the role_id values in the navigation_roles table.